# How to load a style from postgres on a sub request in PyQt

Tags: pyqgis, style, qgis-processing, pyqt

In a qgis-processing script, I'm loading sub-requested layers with x, y, radius to have less data in qgis-desktop. The data is well loaded but I can't apply styles stored in postgresql layer_styles table.
The Qgis layers'name, the f_table_name and the stylename are the sames. Could somebody help me finishing this script?

```
##myscript=group
##x=number 449000
##y=number 219000
##radius=number 500

from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

# list of layers' names
file = open(r"\\fileserver\sig$\symbols\mapping.csv", "r")

for line in file:
    registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()

    # remove existing layers
    for layer in registry.values():
        if (layer.name() == line):
            QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(layer)

    # making the sub request
    part1="(select * from schema."
    part2=" WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(ST_SetSRID(ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint("
    part3=","
    part4="),"
    part5="),3163),geom))"
    sql = part1 + line + part2 +str(x)+ part3 +str(y)+part4+str(radius)+part5

    # building the uri
    uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
    uri.setConnection("192.168.1.71","5432","mybase","me","mypass")
    uri.setDataSource("",sql,"geom","","gid")

    # adding the layer to the registry
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(),line,"postgres")
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
    # applying the style
    vlayer.applyNamedStyle(line)

    if not vlayer.isValid():
        print "layer failed to load"
```